# How to align textview center in relative layout when there is two lines in textview

Tags: android

I want my textview center horizontal in relative layout. I can able to achieve this when my text view contains only one line. If there is two lines in text view,then not able to do that.

This is my layout,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anybody help me to find a better solution.

Comment: Use android:gravity="center" in you textview

Comment: centerHorizontal is centering the actual textview, not the text within it, and sence it is set to wrap content it will grow in width and height as the text becomes longer. gravity="center" will center the actual text within the textview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: android:gravity="center"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is this the entire xml? Because it's working on my pc.

Comment: thank you all...now I am getting it in center.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

Here is the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_centerInParent